# Can't access any website on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, proxy, google

I bought a laptop with Ubuntu for simple browsing and light work, and Ubuntu seemed much nicer than windows. Don't get me wrong, I still love it, but Ubuntu has been giving me problems since day one when I couldn't download anything from the Software Center. Skip forward about two years where I've restarted to factory state and now I cannot access anything In Chrome.

It says:

> This Webpage Is not available. Google chrome cannot reach the website. This is typically caused by network issues, but can also be the result of a misconfigured firewall or proxy server.

So I go into Chrome settings to change my proxy settings and it presents me with this: " when running Google Chrome Under a supported desktop environment, the system proxy settings will be used. However, either your system is not supported or there was a problem launching our system configuration. But you can still configure via the command line. Please see 'man google-chrome-stable' for more information on flags and environment variables.

So now I'm stumped and I don't know what to do. I don't even know where to start. I apologize for being a pain, but if you need me to do anything, you'll have to give me step by step instructions on how to get there. Thank you all for your patience!
After running `sudo apt-get update`:
https://photos.app.goo.gl/cJFZ6QWRDhznPl0W2

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it an issue with only Chrome? Do other browsers (e.g. Firefox) work?

Comment: I'm unable to check. I can't access other browser websites to download them. Chromium won't even open

Comment: Do you have a proxy on your network?  Have you confirmed that your computer is not having any other network issues with, say, package updating or resolving websites otherwise (like on the command line)

Comment: I'm really sorry, I wouldn't know how to check any of those. I really don't mean to be a pain, I'm just so lost in all of this. How would you go about checking it?

Comment: Open a terminal and type `sudo apt-get update` then edit this question and include any error messages you will get.

Comment: When you say you've "restarted to factory state", you mean you've restored from a backup, right? What method did you use to do this?

Comment: As for "restarted to factory state" I used the Dell Recovery to restore the system to the factory shipped state. I didn't recover any files I had, because none of them were important to me. After restoring the system, I went straight to Chrome to find that it didn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix the GPG error "NO\_PUBKEY"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another method to install firefox so that we can narrow down this problem to Chrome:

Open a terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get install firefox -y
```

Entering your password when prompted.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but after installing Firefox, the same thing happens, "server not found"

Comment: Please open a terminal(Keyboard shortcut: Ctrl+Alt+T) and give me the output of this command: 

cat /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: cat /etc/resolv.conf came up with: Dynamic resolv.conf (5) file for glibic resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8) DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGED WILL BE OVERWRITTEN. nameserver 127.0.1.1